# Unable to understand the working of map with has multiset as mapped_type

Tags: c++, containers

I came across a program which aims to print authors names and their books in alphabetic order and tried understanding it

authors is a multimap whose key_type contains authors name and mapped_type contains their book.
Now order_authors being a map, shouldn't it ignore the author name "Stephen King" when it's given for the second time with mapped_type "It" and not use insert. But I don't understand how the program achieves what it's intended for, I request someone to please explain the working

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
using multi_map = std::multimap<string, string>;
multi_map authors =
{ {"Stephen King","Misery"},{"C. S. Lewis","A Grief Observed"},
    {"Stephen King","It"},{"Charles Dickens","Oliver Twist"} };
std::map<string, std::multiset<string>> order_authors;

for (const auto &author : authors)
    order_authors[author.first].insert(author.second);
for (const auto &author : order_authors) {
    cout << author.first << " -> ";
    for (const auto &work : author.second)
        cout << work << ". ";
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Expected and actual output:

C. S. Lewis -> A Grief Observed.

Charles Dickens -> Oliver Twist.

Stephen King -> It. Misery.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward. What's the issue? Perhaps, you need to checkout what multimap/multiset are.

Comment: My issue here is not with multimap/multiset but with map i.e., order_authors. If we try to insert an element with key which is already present it won't be inserted right? But here it's being inserted

Comment: `order_authors` has a `multiset<string>` as values. The `insert` function pushes another string into the multiset.

Comment: @Abdulkareem What are you issuing the `insert` call on?  It isn't the `std::map` `key` element, it is on the `data` element, which is a `multiset`.

Comment: So @ALX23z what you mean is if value type is multiset or multimap of map, then map will not check if the key is already present or not?

Comment: @Abdulkareem What does `order_authors[key]` do? It finds pair `{key,value}` in the map. If one such doesn't exists then it creates a new one. Then returns `value` by reference. Again, `insert` function is not called on `order_authors` but on the `value` that was returned which is a `multiset<string>`.

Comment: @Abdulkareem -- Go back and look at this line: `order_authors[author.first].insert(author.second);` -- You are missing what this part `order_authors[author.first]` does.  If you wanted to not insert into the `map` (not the `multiset`), then you would use the `insert` call on the map, i.e. `order_authors.insert(…);`

Comment: Got it guys! thanks for the explanation